# How to remove component that is rendered from a list? React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been following this [tutorial for ReactJS](https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/cLKWEcZ) and have been trying now to convert the simplistic Todo App (just checks off and on items) to React Native. I've been using expo to try it live on my phone and everything.

It all went good, but now I'm trying to add something. Whenever I click the checkbox I want to remove the component related to that item.

My idea was:

> Since I'm rendering the TodoItem components from an array of todos,
>   and whenever I click a checkbox it updates the array as a whole
>   (looking for a certain id and updating it's completed variable). I can
>   run through the array and whenever the id is different I return the
>   todo. This way I returned every todo but the one with matching id to
>   be rendered.

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { Alert,Image,StyleSheet, Text,Button, View } from 'react-native';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'
import todosData from "./todosData"

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

  }


  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map( todo => {
    if(todo.id !== id) {
      return todo
    }

  })
  return {
    todos:updatedTodos
  }
})
  }
  render() {

const todoItems = this.state.todos.map( item =>
  <TodoItem
    key={item.id}
    item={item}
    handleChange = {this.handleChange}
  />
)
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

    {todoItems}

  </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**This gives an error: ' TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')', giving  at App.js:42:18**

I'll also add the code referring to the TodoItem:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { Alert,Image,StyleSheet, Text,Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
function TodoItem(props) {
  return (
    <View>
    <CheckBox
      checked={props.item.completed}
      onPress={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
    />
    <Text>{props.item.text}</Text>


    </View>
  );
}
export default TodoItem
```

**I don't understand why this won't work**. It feels like I'm deleting the component while still using it (for it to give a undefined), but I don't see where. Since I'm simple updating a list of todos.
**How can I do the thing I want?**

PS: I seem unable to properly format the first segment of code. I apologize for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
handleChange(id) {
  const { todos } = this.state
  // filter out the deleted one
  const filtered = todos.filter(x => x.id !== id)

  this.setState({ todos: filtered })
}
```

We don't want to alter the state directly, but since `.filter()` creates a new array, without touching the given array, it is fine to use it. if it was another operation, you'd do something like this:

```
// create a copy
const newSomethings = [...this.state.somethings]
// do whatever with newSomethings
this.setState({ somethings: newSomethings })
```

Comment: Works! So the idea is to never alter states directly but instead create clones and then replaced the old version with the altered clone?

Comment: @DTek exactly. altering the state directly has side-effects and its unpredictable. the same thing applies to stores like redux, if you ever dive into it. behind the scenes, it does not really rerender/replace everything, even though the code seems like you are replacing the whole state